# SSL java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException

Tags: java, sockets, ssl

Java says that in this line, the file ssc.store was not found:

```
server = ((SSLServerSocketFactory) SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault()).createServerSocket(port);
```

(server is a ServerSocket)

I try to use a libary containing this code, but I am not able to open this ServerSocket.

Full Error

```
Error opening ServerSocket
java.net.SocketException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error 
constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
at javax.net.ssl.DefaultSSLServerSocketFactory.throwException(Unknown Source)
at javax.net.ssl.DefaultSSLServerSocketFactory.createServerSocket(Unknown Source)
at com.blogspot.debukkitsblog.Net.Server.start(Server.java:327)
at com.blogspot.debukkitsblog.Net.Server.<init>(Server.java:86)
at com.blogspot.debukkitsblog.Net.Server.<init>(Server.java:51)
at de.yee.GameServer.<init>(GameServer.java:16)
at de.yee.Main.main(Main.java:9)
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
at java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(Unknown Source)
at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance(Unknown Source)
at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getDefault(Unknown Source)
at javax.net.ssl.SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault(Unknown Source)
... 5 more
Caused by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: ssc.store (Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultManagersHolder.getKeyManagers(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultManagersHolder.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
... 11 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: ssc.store (Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultManagersHolder$2.run(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultManagersHolder$2.run(Unknown Source)
... 19 more
```

What is the problem?

Comment: maybe the library is expecting a `ssc.store` file but it can't find it

Comment: I'm not very familiar with ssls. But mybe it has smth to do with SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault()?

Comment: the getdefault is ok, but it raises a file not found exception. You are using a library and this library makes the ssl calls, is that right?

Comment: I think so, yeah

Comment: which library is it? so others can reproduce the problem

Comment: Here: https://github.com/DeBukkIt/SimpleServerClient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `ssc.store` file in the working directory where you run your code. The store is here: https://github.com/DeBukkIt/SimpleServerClient/blob/master/ssc.store (or in the specific branch or tag you checked out).

For example, if you're running `main` method inside IntelliJ, the store file should be in the project root directory. Or, if you pack your application into a `jar` and run `java -jar yourapp.jar`, the `ssc.store` should be in the same directory as the jar file.

Comment: Thank you! That fixed it :D

Comment: @KevinMeyer if the answer helped you, please consider accepting it